# resending a POST request with file upload from one Laravel app to a second Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to post info from a form in one laravel app to a second laravel app.  Text is fine, the issue is re-sending a photo.

I'm testing this simply in the `routes.php` file at the moment so that instead of sending the request to a seprate app, the request is being sent to itself. Here's my code:

```
Route::get('testpost', function() {
    $html = '<form action="testpost" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><input type="file" accept="image/*" value="Upload Photo" name="photo" id="photo"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit"></form>';
    return $html;
});
Route::post('testpost', function() {
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $guzzle->createRequest('POST', 'https://test1.dev/secondpost', [
        'config' => [
            'curl' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    $postBody = $request->getBody();
    $photo = Input::file('photo');
    $postBody->addFile(new \GuzzleHttp\Post\PostFile('photo', $photo));
    try {
        $response = $guzzle->send($request);
        echo $response;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
});
Route::post('secondpost', function() {
    if(Input::hasFile('photo')) {
        var_dump(Input::file('photo'));
    } else {
        echo 'No photo';
    }
});
```

The output I thne get is:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[9]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'photo' (length=5)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'text/plain' (length=10)
  private 'size' => int 26
  private 'error' => int 0
```

i.e. the image isnt actually being re-uploaded. Anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by doing the following:

```
$photo = Input::file('photo');
$filename = $photo->getClientOriginalName();
$photo->move(storage_path(), $filename);
```

then

```
$request = $guzzle->createRequest();
$postBody = $request->getBody();
$postBody->addFile(new \GuzzleHttp\Post\PostFile('photo', fopen(storage_path() . '/' . $filename, 'r')));
```